# Cannot hit button with eventlistener click when using opacity

Tags: javascript, css, addeventlistener

So i have a question, on why something does not work..
I have a small mobile menu, when i click the main button, i am trying to expand the child items, with some animation.

To start with, i was hiding the child items beneath the main item, and they had opacity 0. 
and then on click, i would set a class on the container, and they would get opacity 1. 
But my event never fires...

But then if i use display:none on them instead of opacity 0, it works fine...

Codepen example: https://codepen.io/andrelange91/pen/abzmoww

**Html**

```
<div class="nav-wheel" id="nav-wheel__container">
  <button class="nav-wheel__main" id="nav-wheel__btn">
    <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
  </button>
  <a class="nav-wheel__sublink">
    <i class="fas fa-truck-pickup"></i>
  </a>
  <a class="nav-wheel__sublink">
    <i class="fas fa-truck-pickup"></i>
  </a>
  <a class="nav-wheel__sublink">
    <i class="fas fa-truck-pickup"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

**Styling**

```
.nav-wheel{
  position:fixed;
  left:50%;
  bottom:5%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-5%);
  .nav-wheel__main, .nav-wheel__sublink{
    background-color:orange;
    border:0;
    color:white;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    border-radius:50%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    box-shadow:0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: all 750ms cubic-bezier(.218,.63,.325,1);
    cursor:pointer;
    &:focus{
      outline:none;
    }
    i.fas{
      font-size:32px;
    }
  }

  .nav-wheel__main{

  }
  .nav-wheel__sublink{
    z-index:-1;
    display:none;
    text-align:center;
    //opacity:0; // no good...

    i.fas{
      margin-top:17px;
    }
  }
  &.active{
    transition: all 750ms cubic-bezier(.218,.63,.325,1);
    .nav-wheel__main{
      z-index:50;
      left:0;
    }
    .nav-wheel__sublink{
      //opacity:1; // no good...
      display:block;

      &:nth-child(2){
        left: -75px;
        bottom: 55px;
      }
      &:nth-child(3){
        left:0;
        bottom:95px;
      }
      &:nth-child(4){
        left: 75px;
        bottom: 55px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
const mainBtn = document.getElementById('nav-wheel__btn');
const mainEle = document.getElementById('nav-wheel__container');

console.log(mainBtn);
console.log(mainEle);

mainBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){

  console.log("button clicked");

  if(mainEle.classList.contains('active')){

    mainEle.classList.remove("active");  

  }else{

    mainEle.classList.add("active");  

  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is working fine except your css.

On rendering you have set **.nav-wheel__main, .nav-wheel__sublink** z-index to **-1**, therefore you made opacity to 0 your child menu start overlapping the button.

Therefore you script stop working corrected CSS provided below.

```
.nav-wheel{
  position:fixed;
  left:50%;
  bottom:5%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-5%);
  .nav-wheel__main, .nav-wheel__sublink{
    background-color:orange;
    border:0;
    color:white;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    border-radius:50%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:11;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    box-shadow:0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: all 750ms cubic-bezier(.218,.63,.325,1);
    cursor:pointer;
    &:focus{
      outline:none;
    }
    i.fas{
      font-size:32px;
    }
  }

  .nav-wheel__main{

  }
  .nav-wheel__sublink{
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0;
    text-align:center;
    //opacity:0; // no good...

    i.fas{
      margin-top:17px;
    }
  }
  &.active{
    transition: all 750ms cubic-bezier(.218,.63,.325,1);
    .nav-wheel__main{
      z-index:50;
      left:0;
    }
    .nav-wheel__sublink{
      opacity:1;

      &:nth-child(2){
        left: -75px;
        bottom: 55px;
      }
      &:nth-child(3){
        left:0;
        bottom:95px;
      }
      &:nth-child(4){
        left: 75px;
        bottom: 55px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: can't belive i missed that ^^ quess i was staring my self blind on it.